# Create a custom posts page

Tags: posts, customization, templates

I've created a template that shows all my blog posts. But the issue was that this page slug (tips-and-tricks) wasn't added to the URL of the single post.

Solution: I've selected this page as my blog page under Settings > Read. Now my url is
`https://domain.com/tips-and-tricks/post-name`.

Issue: When I select the page as my blog page, the custom template isn't used anymore. Wordpress uses the index.php file.

How can I use my custom template for this page?

Answer (score 1):

When you select a page as your blog page, the template that WordPress is looking for is the `home.php` file.

You should really check out the Template Hierarchy from the WordPress documentation as these things are really WordPress basic knowledge. Check out the Template Hierarchy here: https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/

Comment: I did some changes: I've created a home.php file. In that file there's a category loop which shows all the posts in that specific category. That seems to work, except the URL of the single blog post isn't prefixed with the slug of the home.php page.

Comment: You can change the URL prefix of single blog pages via Settings > Permalinks.